# Getting TypeScript compilation error on Object.assign, but everything works great

Tags: typescript

Apparently this is a known issue. The suggested workaround make my IDE stop complaining, and it runs and works fine, but I'm getting Angular CLI build TS errors which cause my CI/CD pipeline to fail.

The offending line is `Object.assign(...args)`, where args is a dynamically sized array of objects, resulting in the below error

> error TS2557: Expected at least 1 arguments, but got a minimum of 0.

Full code and context is

```
_.chain(myObjects)
.groupBy((obj: MyObject) => obj.someParam)
.each((args: [MyObject, MyObject, MyObject]) => {
  Object.assign(...args);
});
```

the 3rd line used to be `args: MyObject[]` but that caused IDE errors, so per various threads including https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4130 I changed it to the above, but I'm still getting the errors on build

As mentioned, it runs and works perfectly, the Object.assign(...args) beautifully merges all objects in the args array. The only issue is that compiler barfs and fails my CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: It's awful but maybe you can use `Object.assign(args[0], args[1])` instead ?

Comment: Or *slightly* less awful (IMHO): `([target, ...rest]: MyObject[]) => { Object.assign(target, ...rest); }`

Comment: @Raphaël it's an arbitrarily long array so that wouldn't quite work

Comment: @p.s.w.g Works like a champ thank you! If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept and send some internet points your way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `Object.assign` requires at least one argument, but the type `MyObject[]` could be an empty array. You have to convince the compiler in some way that there's at least entry in the array. For example:

```
_.chain(myObjects)
.groupBy((obj: MyObject) => obj.someParam)
.each(([target, ...rest]: MyObject[]) => {
  Object.assign(target, ...rest);
});
```

Or if you're comfortable 'cheating' a little with the `as` keyword:

```
_.chain(myObjects)
.groupBy((obj: MyObject) => obj.someParam)
.each((args: MyObject[]) => {
  Object.assign(...args as [MyObject]);
});
```

Comment: Works like a champ! I'm using the first option you listed, and just wrap it in a if to ensure it's not an empty list